# Is it possible to adjust the size of a div in a parent based on the count of divs inside the parent?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I would like to adjust the size of `div` inside parent based on the count of divs ?

For examples :

*Let's say that parent size is 900px*

- If there is only one `div` inside the parent, I would like its size `100%`
- If there are two `div` inside the parent, I would like both the same size: `50%`
- If there are three `div` inside the parent, I would like both the same size: `33,33333%`
- If there are four `div` inside the parent, I would like both the same size: `25%`
- (...)

The maximum number of div is **4** but can be more.

Is it possible to do that **only in CSS** ?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23930785/703717)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is

Here is the CSS for that:

```
/* one item */
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1) {
width: 100%;
}

/* two items */
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2),
div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(1) {
width: 50%;
}

/* three items */
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3),
div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2),
div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(1) {
width: 33.3333%;
}

/* four items */
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4),
div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3),
div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(2),
div:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(1) {
width: 25%;
}
```

---

an even shorter solution would be:

```
/* one item */
div:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
width: 100%;
}

/* two items */
div:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
div:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ div {
width: 50%;
}

/* three items */
div:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
div:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ div {
width: 33.3333%;
}

/* four items */
div:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
div:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ div {
width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Yay ! Works great ! What does this character `~` ?

Comment: Is this possible to make it work on IE with this syntax ? Example : `div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3)` to something like this `div:first-child + div + div`

Comment: the ~ is the siblings selector, it will selects all siblings from the element selected before

Comment: I think this would work, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492121/ie8-nth-child-and-before

Answer (score 1):

The code in SCSS

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
  li:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i}),
  li:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i}) ~ li {
    width: 100% / $i
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes It can be done. using `display: table;` `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`.

It works similar to table structure.

[Check this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kndqg)

CSS

```
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: You need to add a width to your table-cell or this won't work with content - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kqeAu

Comment: Why does your code work with adding a width `25%` and 2 or 3 cells... I don't understand... with the same code, my cells keeps the same size : 25%

Comment: We just need to specify the width, It can also work it you set width: 50%;

Comment: @Steffi can you post a fiddle where your code isn't working, tushar 50% won't work for tables with more than 2 cells

Answer (score 0):

This will work using javascript, html and css.

HTML

```
<div id="outerDiv">

    <div class="innerDiv">
        hello
    </div>
 <div class="innerDiv">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outerDiv
{
   min-height: 500px;
    height:500px;/* any height you want. */
   width:250px; /* any width you want. */
   max-width:250px; /* any whatever width you want. */
border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;

}
.innerDiv{


/* height is set using JS */
   width:250px; /* same as outer div */
   max-width:250px; /* same as outer div */
border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: red;

}
```

JS

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){
var x=parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("div").length)
    x=x-1;
var y=Math.round(100/x);
var z=document.getElementsByClassName("innerDiv");
    for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
    z[i].style.height=y+"%";
    }

}
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6SMqw/2/

You can add as many inner divs as you want inside the outer div, just keep the class-name (innerDiv) same.

Comment: Did you not see the big bold "only in css"

Comment: oops!! ..missed that..thanks for pointing. Anyways i wont delete it incase someone needs to refer it in the future, its not wrong so wont hurt.