# Dynamic equal width children

Tags: css

Is there any way to get all children of a parent to be the same width without having the parent be a block level element?

Basically I want all the "columns" in the jsfiddle to have the same width but I don't want the container to span the entire width of the container, only the necessary width.

Edit: I am looking for a way to handle a dynamic number of children

Edit2: Updated the fiddle and code to make widths more obvious

Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
  Short
  </div>
  <div>
  SomethingSuperLong
  </div>
  <div>
  Ok
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0g9af1dh/2

Comment: Is 'flex: 1;' on the children not what you're looking for?

Comment: Basically, no there isn't....not without javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below snippet.

```js
var maxWidth = 0;
$('.container > div').each(function() {
  var thisWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
  if(maxWidth < thisWidth) {
    maxWidth  = thisWidth;
  }
});
$('.container > div').width(maxWidth);
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Short
  </div>
  <div>
    Something super long
  </div>
  <div>
    Ok
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: May be if you are open for script as well. Neglect otherwise.

Comment: display: flex makes this a block level element, which I am trying to avoid

Comment: I just want to check if you are open for script level workaround.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid javascript if possible. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

So, the capabilities of flex, but with inline behavior? Hmmm...

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.container > div {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
  Short
  </div>
  <div>
  Something super long
  </div>
  <div>
  Ok
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated the fiddle to make it more obvious. If you use inspector you will notice those 3 columns are not the same width. I made SomethingSuperLong one word to make it a bit clearer for other people experimenting

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just want them to be the same size you can do it like this.

```
.container > div {
width: 33.3%;
}
```

If it's not what you want, tell me in the comments and I will update it.

Comment: This requires the container to be a block level element

Answer (score 0):

just change your css to

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container > div {
  flex:1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: display: flex makes this a block level element, which I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

[my solution](https://jsfiddle.net/okahara/0g9af1dh/4/) is very similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930684/allocate-equal-width-to-child-elements-with-css)

But in his solution he left them as `display: table` which makes the outer div share qualities of `display: block`

If you change it to use `display: inline-table` it takes on inline characters. To show that it is inline I placed `test inline` next to the outer div.

This solution does require you set a width for your outer container. Based on your question details I think this works for you but if it doesn't let me know and I can tweak the answer.